# SQLITE asking for password in laravel migration

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

I made SQLite as my default database in Laravel, why is it that PHP artisan migrate is still asking for credentials?

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES)

Comment: You have to first create the file. Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database

Comment: I already created database.sqlite

Comment: What is `default` set to in your database.php? Your error looks like mysql instead of sqlite.

Comment: @mihkel worked now, some env setup based on the link you provided, thanks.

Comment: `Access denied for the using that password`, that means the password might be wrong or  homestead user may not have access to do that opertaion.